# How to calculate maximum from pivot table in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have written code to calculate the count of feature3 groupby feature1 and feature2

```
pd.pivot_table(data=train, index=['feature1', 'feature2'], values=['feature3'], aggfunc='count')
```

Who's output is:

```
feature1 feature2 feature3  
129001  0   4
        1   10
        2   11
        3   22
        4   26
        5   38
129002  0   6
        2   45
        5   25
```

Now I want to calculate max of feature3 groupby feature1

```
feature1 feature3
129001    38
129002    45
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to clarify the data?

Comment: what clarification do you need?

Comment: Lots, suggest you check how to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

You need the following statement:

```
df.groupby(level=0)['feature3'].max()
```

Start with the results of your `pivot_table`

```
print(df)
                   feature3
feature1 feature2          
129001   0                4
         1               10
         2               11
         3               22
         4               26
         5               38
129002   0                6
         2               45
         5               25
```

`groupby` with `level 0` of your index and `max`:

```
df.groupby(level=0)['feature3'].max()
```

Output:

```
feature1
129001    38
129002    45
Name: feature3, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
                   feature3
feature1 feature2
129001   0                4
         1               10
         2               11
         3               22
         4               26
         5               38
129002   0                6
         2               45
         5               25

In [22]: df.max(level='feature1')
Out[22]:
          feature3
feature1
129001          38
129002          45
```

Comment: I like this way.